# Wordpress + Wpml translated slug of custom post type with custom url rewrite

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, wpml

We have strange problem in one project with wpmpl translated custom post type slug in combination with custom url rewrite.

```
Custom post type slug "work"
Custom taxonomy "work-type"
```

Url rewritten in format (via "Custom post type permalink" plugin) in format: "/post-type (work)/%work-type%/%postname%/"

```
WPML translated slugs (en primary) "work" + (sk) "praca"
```

In primary language everything works fine e.g. "/work/development/postname"

But in secondary language its still redirecting to permalink "/sk/work/development-sk/postname-sk" when development-sk is Slovak association of "work-type" taxonomy and "postname-sk" is Slovak version of english postname (which is correct)

Not correct is, that "work" slug is not rewritten.

When i deactivate this rewrite, it works fine, but URL is without "work-type" taxonomy in URLs, so correctly working url in Slovak language is "/sk/praca/postname-sk"

Have you any idea how to make working this custom post type with custom taxonomy slug in URL in combination with WPML slug rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Did you translate this slug in WPML > Translation management > Multilingual content setup? You should do this there.

For more question please try to ask WPML forum https://wpml.org/forums/ Buying WPML you get free support